# Uploading Arduino Sketch via Visual Studio with Variables

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, arduino, rfid

So I have my application and arduino connected via serial communication and the project works like I want it to so far. The arduino is currently connected to an RFID board and intakes scanned RFID tags and saves them to a database. What I want to do now is to run my visual studio application which will generate a RFID code. Is it possible to add this RFID code variable to the arduino sketch, so that if that RFID code is scanned a red LED will flash.

Basically I really want to know is if I can pass a variable value from my visual studio application into a variable in my arduino sketch and then upload that sketch to the arduino board, all through the visual studio application while its running?

I'm currently using the visual micro plugin to use the arduino in visual studio.

Thanks for any help or advice!

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to hardcode that value in the Arduino executable rather than sending the value over e.g. a serial interface to the running Arduino application?

Comment: You could paste the code that contains the variable that you want to modify. This might help us understand why you want to update the code with visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Serial/Usb to send the variable to the sketch while it is running.